# Mysql Insert PHP colons, semi colons and double quotes

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

i am writing a custom script to insert data into a wordpress database. The database contains an address section and the data in the field has various colons, semi colons and double quotes. I am having a hard time trying to write the php mysql insert statement. Getting a lot of syntax errors.

The Field looks like:

```
a:9:{s:8:"address1";s:7:"street1";s:8:"address2";s:7:"street2";s:4:"city";s:9:"London";s:5:"state";s:5:"Bucks";s:11:"postal_code";s:8:"MK49 8UY";s:7:"country";s:2:"GB";s:13:"logo_image_id";s:1:"0";s:5:"notes";s:0:"";s:12:"instructions";s:0:"";}
```

Can anyone offer any guidance on how to escape such a large number of characters

Comment: Use a prepared statement, no escaping necessary.

Comment: That's a (serialized array)[http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php] (with an error, BTW). Just build your array normally and use the `serialize` function.

Answer (score 0):

As Roberto Suggests - if you are attempting to insert a pre formatted serialized array into your database (and it has an error) it's not going to work. If you are collecting all the data individually and building it the simpler way to go about this would be to first construct the array, then convert it to a format that can be stored in the database easily (serialised arrays). Example:

```
$address = array(
 'address1'    => 'Street1',
 'address2'    => 'Street2',
 'city'        => 'London',
 'state'       => 'bucks',
 'postal_code' => 'MK49 8UY',
 'country'     => 'GB',
);

$formattedAddress = serialize($address);
// returns
// a:6:{s:8:"address1";s:7:"Street1";s:8:"address2";s:7:"Street2";s:4:"city";s:6:"London";s:5:"state";s:5:"bucks";s:11:"postal_code";s:8:"MK49 8UY";s:7:"country";s:2:"GB";}
```

You can now reference $address within your insert statement to get a correctly formatted serialized array.